# Identify this game about using 3 cards sets to take control of Pawns

Tags: identify-this-game

Help me identify this game about taking control of a row of Pawns with Flushes and Straights made of 3 cards. Here are some aspects I remember:

- It's a two player game.
- It's an older card game + where you line up like 7-10 pawns.
- I believe there are 6 suits.
- Game play starts with some number of cards (5-7?)
- I think you draw two cards per turn, play one in front of a Pawn (on your side) and discard the other.
- The goal of the game is capture either 3 consecutive pawns in the row, or capture the majority of Pawns.
- You capture a pawn by playing 3 cards on your side and beating the opponents 3 with standard card rules. (Best to Worst - Straight Flushes > Flush > Straight > High Card)
- I know there are 4-6 "ability cards" that let you move cards around or something like that.
- I believe the original version of the card game was vaguely Greek or Roman soldier/warrior inspired, though I know other people have reskinned it as Star Wars on Tabletop Sim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Battle Line](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/760/battle-line) or [Schotten Totten](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/372/schotten-totten) may be what you're looking for.

> Two opponents face off across a 'battle line' and attempt to win the battle by taking 5 of 9 flags or 3 adjacent flags. Flags are decided by placing cards into 3 card poker-type hands on either side of the flag (similar to straight flush, 3 of a kind, straight, flush, etc). The side with the highest 'formation' of cards wins the flag.

> This is a rethemed version of Schotten Totten with different graphics and wooden flag bits in place of the boundary stone cards. Game play is identical, except the cards run from 1 to 10 (not 9), you hold seven cards in your hand (not 6), and the rule that stones may only be claimed at the start of your turn is presented as an "advanced variant". Also the tactics cards were introduced by Battle Line; these cards were only added to later editions of Schotten-Totten.

[image]